# Highlighting searched text in django

Tags: django, django-templates

Here I am writing my custom template filter in order to highlight the matched searched texts.But it is not working properly.What is happening here is it is highlighting only the exactly matched text.For example If i searched `django` but if in the title it is `Django` it  ignores the `Django`.

I want to make it case insensitive so that if the user search `django` then `DJANGO` should also be highlighted.

```
register = template.Library()
@register.filter(name='highlight')
def highlight(text,search):
    highlighted = text.replace(search, '<b class="text text-danger">{}</b>'.format(search))
    return mark_safe(highlighted)
```

views.py

```
def search_blogs(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q')
    if q:
        blogs = Blog.objects.filter(title__icontains=q).order_by('-created')
        return render(request,'blog/search_blogs.html',{"blogs":blogs,'q':q})
    else:
        messages.error(request,'Please enter some keyword to search')
        return redirect('blog:blogs')
```

template

```
{{blog.title|highlight:q}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of a regular expression here:

```
from re import IGNORECASE, compile, escape as rescape

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='highlight')
def highlight(text, search):
    rgx = compile(rescape(search), IGNORECASE)
    return mark_safe(
        rgx.sub(
            lambda m: '<b class="text text-danger">{}</b>'.format(m.group()),
            text
        )
    )
```